# Is this a valid argument to show whether an extremum is isolated?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

So I was wondering if this method was correct/sufficient/convenient to determine whether an extremum is isolated. I looked at other methods, such as looking at the Hessian Matrix and its Eigenvalues, but I found that to be a lot of work in some cases, so if what I'm thinking works or goes in the right direction, I imagine that to be faster, at least for the questions that I have been looking at.
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}, (x,y)\mapsto x^4+x^5+y^6\;$. I wanna find the extrema and determine whether they're isolated.
Finding the partial derivatives:
$$f_x=4x^3+5x^4 \qquad \mbox{and} \qquad f_y=6y^5$$
Therefore: $$\;\; 6y^5=0 \iff y=0$$
And: $$\qquad \; \; 4x^3+5x^4=0 \iff x=0, x=-\frac{4}{5} $$
This means that $\nabla f = \mathbf{0} $ for $ (x,y)= (0,0)$ and $(x,y)=(-0.8,0)$
Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^6$. Because $g$ is a parabola it is strictly monotonic in the neighbourhood around vertex $(0,0)$, decreasing before the vertex and increasing after.
Let $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^4+x^5$. We can see that in the neighbourhood of the critical point at $x=0$ the function $h$ is also strictly monotonic, decreasing before the origin and increasing after. Therefore the graph of $f$ at (0,0) is a local extrema that is isolated, because it is increasing in all directions. However, at the critical point at $x=-0.8$ the function $h$ is strictly increasing on $(-\infty , 0.8)$, whereas $g$ is decreasing on that interval, therefore the function $f$ is not behaving the same way in all directions, meaning that the extrema is not isolated (saddle point).

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct and what you are doing is an analysis of the Hessian matrix :)

The main reason you can break it down is that the Hessian is a diagonal matrix (your derivates in x and y direction are only dependend on one variable).

Normally you dont have that luxury, so you have to look at the whole matrix at once. 
If you work with easily separable functions, what you are doing is fine.